# Add years, months and days to date C

Tags: c, algorithm, date, leap-year

I am trying to write an algorithm that takes an input of a date ("2000-01-01") and also "y|m|d", where y is the number of years to add to the original date and m and d are the months and days. This algorithm needs to take into account leap years as well. Sorry I haven't posted any code, I haven't really got anything working yet.

The algorithm also needs to work like this: if you add three months to 30th November, you would get 28th February the next year, or 29th if it is a leap year. So if the month you are coming from as a length higher than the final resultant month, the last day of the final resultant month will be taken.

Could someone please give me some pointers on how to write it or link to any useful resources?

I hope that this makes sense, any questions let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The question already specifies the problem quite clearly, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: what, if you add 3 months and 1 day to your example? will it be the first of march? what if starting with 28th of November plus one month and a day? is it the 29th if possible else the 1 of next month?

Comment: you need to use `strtok` and `strtol` to parse the fields and convert them into numbers. Then you just need to define the rules you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the problem quite well figured out. Here is the algorithm for finding a leap year:

```
if year is not divisible by 4 then common year
else if year is not divisible by 100 then leap year
else if year is not divisible by 400 then common year
else leap year
```

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all of what you need can be found in the `<ctime>` library (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/).

In particular look up the `time_t` and `struct tm` types and how to convert between the two (`localtime()`, `gmttime()`, ...). Note that you can add days, hours, months, etc to the fields in a `struct tm` and they are handled properly, e.g., the "32nd of January" becomes "Feb. 1st".

The `<ctime>` library also handles leap years.

Your way of adding 3 months seems non conventinal, so you might have to check this by hand. Still easy enough by using `<ctime>`.

**EDIT:** Before somebody complains that `<ctime>` is c++, in plain c this library is in `<time.h>`.